# ifstream::eof throws a type error when in if statement

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a class A that has a std::ifstream filestr member. In one of the class functions I test to see if the stream has reached eof.

```
class A
{
private:
   std::ifstream filestr;

public:
   int CalcA(unsigned int *top);  
}
```

Then in the cpp file I have

```
int CalcA(unsigned int *top)
{
   int error;
   while(true)
   {
      (this->filestr).read(buffer, bufLength);

      if((this->filestr).eof);
      {
         error = 1;
         break;
      }
   }
   return error;
}
```

I get a compile error

```
error: argument of type ‘bool (std::basic_ios<char>::)()const’ does not match ‘bool’
```

Can anyone tell me how to properly use eof? Or any other reasons why I get this error?

Comment: Aside from missing parenthesis, note that use of `eof()` is only useful to determine why a read operation failed. It is pretty useless to be used as a loop control condition.

Comment: Two things. First, `this->` isn't needed in the two places where it appears; that means you can also remove the parentheses. Second, as others have mentioned, `eof` is a function; you have to call it. But it doesn't tell you that you've reached the end of the file; it tells you that you've tried to read past the end of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`eof` is a function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof), so it needs to called like other functions: `eof()`.

That said, the reading loop given can be written *more correctly* (taking into account other possibilities for failure other than end-of-file) without a call to `eof()`, but turning the read operation into the loop condition:

```
while(filestr.read(buffer, bufLength)) {
    // I hope there's more to this :)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(this->filestr).eof())
```

`(this->filestr).eof` alone is a pointer to member method. `if` statements requires exprensions of type `bool`. So you need to call the method. That will succeed because it returns a `bool` value.

Comment: `(this->filestr).eof` is not a pointer to member function. If it were, the code would be fine, because pointers to member functions can be contextually converted to `bool`. The syntax for a pointer to member function is `&ClassName::MemberFunctionName`. Member functions aren't like C functions: their names don't decay into pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`(this->filestr).eof` is not calling the function. `(this->filestr).eof()` is. :-) This explains your error.